# Regular expression for 1-15?

Tags: regex

I'm having difficulty putting together a regular expression for a numeric input of 0-15.

I have tried this expression:

```
^([9]{1,1}|[0-1][0-5])$   

<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="TMPFiltered" runat="server" FilterMode="ValidChars"
                                                FilterType="Custom" ValidChars^([9]{1,1}|[0-1][0-5])$" TargetControlID="txtTMP" />
```

however it is allowing for higher maximums than 15. Where is my syntax incorrect? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why do you have to use a regex?

Comment: Its not for maths, I never said that. It's for an edit extender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there

`^([1-9]|1[0-5])$` is what you need

The only change i made in your regex `[9]{1,1}` to `[1-9]`..no need of `{1,1}` since its already matching 1 time in `[9]`

Comment: Almost working! However it is allowing 5 and 9 in both digit places.

Comment: Yes but this expression is allowing 50,51,52,53 etc.. and 90,91,92,93 etc...

Comment: This is exactly what I have:    <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="TMPFiltered" runat="server" FilterMode="ValidChars"
                                                    FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="^([1-9]|1[0-5])$" TargetControlID="txtTMP" />

Comment: @Ted use [RegularExpressionValidator control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)

Comment: @Ted **FilteredTextBoxExtender** doesnt work with regex

Comment: If you need this in the middle of a string the answer is (1(?![6-9])[0-5]?|(?<!\d)[2-9](?!\d))

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
^([0]?[1-9]|1[0-5])$
```

or try this if you dont want to match like "07"

```
^([1-9]|1[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not the right solution for this, you should just try to convert the string to an int and if that succeeds make sure the result is in your desired range.

That being said, here is a regex that should work:

```
^(1[0-5]?|[2-9])$
```

The primary issue with your current regex is that the anchors are only applied to the left side of the alternation, so you will match strings that match `[0-1][0-5]` anywhere in the regex.  You also don't have any way in your current regex to just match numbers from 2 to 8.

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/HUNZZymzFW

Comment: Isn't working correctly...still allowing the first digit to go 1-9.

Comment: @Ted I don't think so; unless the first digit is the only digit, of course.

Comment: Could it be the FilteredTextBoxExtender control? I'm using your exact expression...