# filteredtextboxextender validchars regular expression asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, regex

i need to validate Mobile number so i user ajax filteredtextboxextender

like below code

```
     <ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" TargetControlID="Mobile_Code" ValidChars="[+]{0,1}" FilterType="Custom,Numbers" runat="server"></ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

but its allowing + for 5 times so i tried in regular expression .its not working....
i need it should allow only One + e.g (+9600114477)

where i made error ,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

`^\+[0-9]{6,8}$`   here, 6 at least number of digit and 8 max number of digit

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^\+[0-9]{6,8}$"   required />
<input type="submit" value="ok"   />
```

**More ref.** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx  [Regular expression for 1-15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127359/regular-expression-for-1-15)

Comment: its working but could pls tell how to do with ajax FilteredTextBoxExtender

Comment: I don't know ajax FilteredTextBoxExtender. I use only regex. You try to use this `^\+[0-9]{6,8}$` regex like other simple regex. it may work...